Prove a bounded condition and decreasing sequence converging to zero imply series convergence.
I am studying series in mathematics and have encountered a theorem which states that the sequence $\\{a_n\\}$ is monotonically decreasing and approaches zero as $n$ approaches infinity. More formally, if:

The sequence $\\{a_n\\}$ is monotonically decreasing, and
$\\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$,
The sum of the differences:

\[
S_n = (a_1-a_n) + (a_2-a_n) + \cdots + (a_{n-1}-a_n)
\]
is bounded,
Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent.
My Atempt
I believe that since $\sum_ {k=1}^{n}a_k-na_{n}$ is bounded, it implies that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ and $na_{n}$ have the same convergence or divergence behavior. However, when I attempted to use proof by contradiction, assuming that $\sum_{n}^{\infty}a_{n}$ diverges, I could not find a contradiction.
I'm looking for a straightforward way to solve this problem that can help me thoroughly understand what the condition of the bounded sum of differences truly implies. Can someone assist me? Thank you!

Let us start with some heuristics. If we see $\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ as some “integral” $F(n)$, we want to show that $F(n)$ is bounded as $n\to\infty$. Your first and second assumption provide that $a_n\approx F'(n)$ decreases to $0$, while the third assumption translates to $F(n)-nF'(n)=O(1)$. This leads us to introduce $G(n):=\frac{F(n)}{n}$, because then $G'(n)=\frac{nF'(n)-F(n)}{n^2}=O(\frac1{n^2})$ gives you, by integration, $G(n)=O(\frac1n)$, so $F(n)=O(1)$.
Now, formalizing the above:

Your first assumption shows that $(S_n)_{n\ge0}$ is nonnegative.
Your second assumption entails that $\sigma_n:=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k\to0$ (by Stolz−Cesàro's theorem).
By your third assumption, $(S_n)_{n\ge0}$ is also bounded from above. Hence $0\le S_n\le C$ for all $n\ge1$ and some $C>0$.
We can see that
\begin{align*}
\sigma_n-\sigma_{n+1}
&=\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\sum_{k=1}^na_k-\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}\\[.4em]
&=\frac1{n(n+1)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k-na_{n+1}\right)\\[.4em]
&=\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)S_{n+1},
\end{align*}
hence
$$0\le\sigma_n-\sigma_{n+1}\le\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)C.\tag{$\star$}$$
Since the right-hand side is $O(\frac1{n^2})$, it follows that the series $\Sigma(\sigma_n-\sigma_{n+1})$ is convergent. By summing the inequality $(\star)$ from $n$ up to $\infty$, we get (recall $\sigma_n\to0$)
$$0\le\sigma_n\le\frac Cn.$$
Thus the sequence $(n\sigma_n)_{n\ge1}$, that is, the nonnegative series $(\sum_{k=1}^na_k)_{n\ge0}$ is bounded from above (by the same constant $C$). We conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$.


Thank you very much, your solution is very insightful and hits the nail on the head, you're so talented, thank you!!

This is not a solution. Just some remarks, should have been in the comments.
Note, $\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_{n}$ is an increasing sequence, since $a_n>0.$ So either convergent to a finite number or divergent to infinity.
If $ma_{m}$ is a bounded sequence, then $\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_{n}=S_{m}+ma_{m}, m=1,2,3,\ldots$ is a bounded sequence, since $S_m$ is bounded. Hence  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is convergent.
If $ma_{m}$ is not a bounded sequence, then there is a subsequence $m_{k} a_{m_k}\to\infty,$ as $k\to.$ Since $S_{m_k}$ is bounded, then $\sum_{n=1}^{m_k}a_{n}\to\infty,$ as $k\to\infty,$ as well. Consequently,  $\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_{n}$ is not bounded, hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is divergent.

Thanks!I know it.So how should I prove the theorem in the problem?

Apologies, perhaps due to my limited English proficiency, I misunderstood your intention. Didn't you explain the relationship between the divergence of $na_n$ and prime numbers, but it seems that it did not prove the theorem in my title, namely the proof of convergence of prime numbers under those conditions? Thank you for your patience!

There are no prime numbers in the title of this problem.

Very sorry,my question is :if:

The sequence $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing, and

2.$\ lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$,
and for any positive integer $n\geq2$, the sum of the differences:
$$S_n=(a_1-a_n)+(a_2-a_n)+\cdots+(a_{n-1}-a_n)$$
is bounded.Please prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent.
